# Freezing of BERT layers while using tfhub module

Tags: tensorflow, bert-language-model, tensorflow-hub

In this link [click here](https://medium.com/@prasad.pai/how-to-use-tensorflow-hub-with-code-examples-9100edec29af) the author says that:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
module = hub.Module(<<Module URL as string>>, trainable=True)
```

If user wishes to fine-tune/modify the weights of the model, this parameter has to be set as True.
So my doubt is if I set this to false does it mean that I am freezing all the layers of the BERT which is my intension too. I want to know if my approach is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a multi-part answer for you.

### How to freeze a Module

It all comes down to how your optimizer is set up. The usual approach for TF1 is to initialize it with all Variables found in the TRAINABLE_VARIABLES [collection](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys). The [doc for hub.Module](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/api_docs/python/hub/Module) says about `trainable`: "If False, no variables are added to TRAINABLE_VARIABLES collection, ...". So, **yes**, setting `trainable=False` (explicitly or by default) freezes the module in the standard usage of TF1.

### Why not to freeze BERT

That said, BERT is meant to be fine-tuned. The [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805) talks about the *feature-based* (i.e., frozen) vs *fine-tuning* approaches in more general terms, but the [module doc](https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_cased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1) spells it out clearly: **"fine-tuning all parameters is the recommended practice."** This gives the final parts of computing the pooled output a better shot at adapting to the features that matter most for the task at hand.

If you intend to follow this advice, please also mind [tensorflow.org/hub/tf1_hub_module#fine-tuning](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tf1_hub_module#fine-tuning) and pick the correct graph version: BERT uses [dropout](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0580) regularization during training, and you need to set `hub.Module(..., tags={"train"})` to get that. But for inference (in evaluation and prediction), where dropout does nothing, you omit the `tags=` argument (or set it to the empty `set()` or to `None`).

### Outlook: TF2

You asked about `hub.Module()`, which is an API for TF1, so I answered in that context. The same considerations apply for [BERT](https://tfhub.dev/google/collections/bert/1) in TF2 SavedModel format. There, it's all about setting `hub.KerasLayer(..., trainable=True)` or not, but the need to select a graph version has gone away (the layer picks up Keras' `training` state and applies it under the hood).

Happy training!

Comment: Your answer has so much information in itself. I was unaware that there models called Small BERT also. But yes the recommendation of fine tuning the model is acceptable. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is it mandatory to add `tags=train` in the `create model` function because there's a;ready a line of code `output_layer = tf.nn.dropout(output_layer, keep_prob=0.9)` to add dropout. @arnoegw

Comment: It's one thing to add dropout to module outputs but another to use the dropout at various places inside the module.